# Python folium synchronizing 2 markerclusters

Tags: python, folium

I have a situation, where I decided to distinguish my markers slightly by adding the MarkerCluster to the existing Marker.
The clustering works, although isn't synchronized. It means, that if I switch one layer off, just the first markercluster disappears, whereas the second criterion defined as CircleMarker still appears like shown below.

[image]

My code is:

```
 df = pd.read_csv("or_geo.csv")
 fo=FeatureGroup(name="OR",overlay = True)
 openreach_cluster = MarkerCluster(name="OR").add_to(map)
 openreach_status = MarkerCluster(control=False,
                             visible=True
                             ).add_to(map)
 for i,row in df.iterrows():
   lat =df.at[i, 'lat']
   lng = df.at[i, 'lng']
   sp = df.at[i, 'sp']
   stat = df.at[i,'status'] 
   popup = df.at[i,'sp'] +'<br>' + str(df.at[i, 'street']) + '<br>' + str(df.at[i, 'post code']) + '<br>{}'.format(style)

   or_marker = folium.Marker(location=[lat,lng], tooltip='<strong>Job details</strong>', popup=popup, icon = folium.Icon(
    color='blue', icon='glyphicon-calendar'))

 or_stat_marker = folium.CircleMarker(
    location=[lat,lng],
    radius=10,
    color=or_color(stat),
    fill_color=or_color(stat),
    fill_opacity=0.5)

 openreach_cluster.add_child(or_marker)
 openreach_status.add_child(or_stat_marker)
```

Is there any way to combine these markerClusters together or sync them?

UPDATE:

The first approach from the answer below, unfortunately, doubles the jobs up and the user can't see them until clicks on any of them shown below:

[image]

This option would be fantastic if the behavior could be the same as in the image above.

UPDATE II:

The second approach is still not what I am looking for, because the clusters are doubled again and after clicking the circlemarker falls almost in the opposite direction as presented in the image above.
I need to have the behaviors exactly like those displayed on the top-left image. The circlemarker should be integrated with the point marker.

Comment: Besides all other ideas i had ... have you thought about using another marker-style or perhaps just design it yourself with a circle at the bottom? :-D

Comment: Hmm, do you mean customizing the clustering with the circle at the bottom\/ \ I don't think it will work, because the particular color of that circle means the status of the order, therefore it's rather an individual issue.

Comment: yes, thats what I meant. I was not aware of the different color meanings

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, I think there are two possibilities:

### Use the same cluster

Add your markers from `or_stat_marker` to the `openreach_cluster` and not to another cluster to de-/activate them at the same time with the same button

```
# was
openreach_cluster.add_child(or_marker)
openreach_status.add_child(or_stat_marker)

# try this
openreach_cluster.add_child(or_marker)
openreach_cluster.add_child(or_stat_marker)
```

### Use marker subgroups

In this case you will have three checkmarks, one parent and two childs for each markercluster which gives full control to visibility

UPDATE: If you add the `control=False` option to the subgroup you will only see the parent group in LayerControl which then show/hide both groups. But the matter of markers "spreading for visibility" still is a problem I think

Another UPDATE: You are able to deactivate the clustering according to the map zoom level or even at all by using `disableClusteringAtZoom` option (use `True` or an `int` number for zoom level). See [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#customising-spiderfy-shape-positions) for reference

```
# markergroups in layercontrol
mc = folium.plugins.MarkerCluster(name='OR',
                                  overlay=True,
                                  control=True,
                                  show=True,
                                  disableClusteringAtZoom=15)  # choose zoom lvl to your needs
mc.add_to(map)
sub1 = folium.plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(mc, name='openreach_cluster', control=False, show=True)  # False --> deactivated at start
sub1.add_to(map)
sub2 = folium.plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(mc, name='openreach_status', control=False)
sub2.add_to(map)

# the layercontrol itself
lc = folium.map.LayerControl(collapsed=False)
lc.add_to(map)

# ...

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    # ...
    or_marker = folium.Marker(...)
    or_marker.add_to(sub1)

    or_stat_marker = folium.CircleMarker(...)
    or_stat_marker.add_to(sub2)
```

My Result:
[image]
By following the second approach described I get a map shown here. There is one checkmark "Segment Markers" which shows/hides the markers including the circles. They don't move around when clicked and are fully shown when zoomed in to a specific lvl by using `disableClusteringAtZoom`.

Sorry this didn't work for your problem, I really don't know why ..

Comment: Updated the question - it's a right track, but it doubles markers up and the circle is visible just after a click.

Comment: Is your picture taken from the first or the second approach I described?

Comment: The first one. The second one works, but it's not what I want, because I have two separate layers to switch on/off. I just want one, that's why I called this question as the "integration" of the clusters.

Comment: Seems like a folium feature to move markers if they are at the same place, so that both are visible (for first approach). At second approach you should be able to hide both layers with one click by deactivating the "parent" layer called OR. Perhaps there is an option to hide the checkboxes of the sublayers. Have to think about it.

Comment: I think with the second update to the second approach it should do the trick, have a look @MKR. Or even use disableClustering for approach number one

Comment: disableClustering would make sense since the one clustering is needed to be honest. I will back to it tomorrow.

Comment: The result is exactly the same as the first one.

Comment: Thats a pity as it worked for me, added a screenshot. Good luck trying further!

Comment: In your picture attached you have got segmental markers but no clustering provided.

Comment: clustering appears when you zoom out some levels, it depends on the value disableClusteringAtZoom