# Python folium Masrker and circle appear separately in featuregroup

Tags: python, folium, folium-plugins

I would like to add the marker and circle that appeared at the same time and bound together as one object.

I used the following code:|

```
 f = pd.read_csv("sur.csv")

 surv = MarkerCluster(name="Surveyors").add_to(m)
 m.add_child(surv)

 su1 = plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(surv, "JB")
 m.add_child(su1)

 if name == "JB":
    folium.Marker(location=[lat,lng], popup=popup, icon = folium.Icon(color='white', 
 icon='house', prefix='fa',  icon_color='green')).add_to(su1)

    folium.Circle([lat,lng],
                      radius=32186,
                      tooltip = tooltip,
                      color='green',
                      fill=True,
                      fill_color='darkgreen',
                      opacity=0.25,
                      fill_opacity=0.1
                      ).add_to(su1)
```

but they appear separately and after clicking.

Is there a way to keep them together as one object?
[image]

Comment: I wanted to link you this answer but by comparing the author of the question I think you already know it :-D https://stackoverflow.com/a/74348366/13843906